# Unable to compile a simple C++17 program

Tags: c++, c++17

I am trying to use C++17 `if constexpr` feature but fail to compile a simple function.

Code:

```
template <auto B>
int foo()
{
    if constexpr(B)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 2;
    }
}  // <- I get an error here 

int main()
{
    return foo<false>();
}
```

The error output by compiler:

```
<source>(12): error #1011: missing return statement at end of non-void function "foo<B>() [with B=false]"

  }
```

Used `-std=c++17 -O3 -Wall -Werror` compiler flags and `icc 19.0.1` compiler.

Is this valid C++17 code?
What is the reason behind this error?

Comment: Why have an `else` after a `return`? Why not `if constexpr(B)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 2;` ?

Comment: Works with g++ https://godbolt.org/z/h4jhZ1

Comment: @JesperJuhl I can't always do that. For example, what if my else branch does not compile when B is true. I can write `if (not B)`. But I expected this to work. That's the main issue.

Comment: Obviously the compiler didn't notice that all code paths (both branches) contain a return statement and thus issued a warning, which is not justified, though. And as you turned all warnings into errors, the code doesn't compile...

Comment: @Aconcagua I am guessing compiler need only recognize the function returns in else branch. Why does the compiler care if I return or not in the if branch? I am only instantiating with `B = false`.

Comment: @TrickorTreat That would actually suffice, yes, but you might get different warnings in different compilation units depending on which path actually is active there. Might be preferable to see all warnings concerning the same function at the same place. Doesn't change anything, though, all code paths return, so there shouldn't be a warning at all, no matter how you instantiate the template.

Comment: I think we agree this is a compiler bug? Please report this to Intel if you can.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this valid C++17 code?

Yes, it's valid. Exactly one return statement will be discarded, while the other will remain. Even if none remain, C++ still allows you to omit a return statement from a function. You get undefined behavior if the function's closing curly brace is reached, but that's a risk only if execution reaches that point.

In your case, execution cannot reach such a point, so UB is not possible.

> What is the reason behind this error?

You used `-Werror`, thus turning the compiler's false positive warning into a hard error. One workaround is to disable this warning around that particular function. This is purely a quality of implementation problem.

Comment: Strange that compiler fired a false positive on such simple code. I will disable the warning like you suggested, Thanks.

Comment: @TrickorTreat - Compilers do it all the time. Just means the code needs to be analyzed by a human, and the diagnostic adjusted.

Comment: This is my first time encountering such an issue. I expected `-Wall` flag to work most of the time and such failure cases would be rare.